# How do I programmatically make the "dictate" keyboard key be pressed in iOS (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, siri

I need to make the "dictate" microphone is the iPhone 4S be programmatically pressed, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot control Siri from any public API.

Comment: Hate to be anal about this- but I don't think the question is about 'Siri'.

Comment: The 'dictate' keyboard is a function of Siri.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you just will not be able to upload it to the AppStore, since you would have to use non-public APIs.

Comment: Can you elaborate Oscar? I'm writing an enterprise app that won't go into the app store and wanted to see how to do this. Thanks!