# Can I create a button that starts Voice Dictation mode in iOS?

Tags: ios

I understand this is a bad idea (to show a voice dictation button in the app when it's already on the keyboard when it's available). But I have a client who would really like to have a microphone icon in a text field that would enter voice dictation mode when pressed.

Note, I am talking about the standard OS voice dictation mode (that the keyboard controls).

So the basic question is:

Can I tell the keyboard to enter voice dictation mode?

(my guess is that it's not allowed, but I would love something more "official" than my gut)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically make the "dictate" keyboard key be pressed in iOS (Objective C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732252/how-do-i-programmatically-make-the-dictate-keyboard-key-be-pressed-in-ios-obj)

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't be possible unless you were to jailbreak your device. There would be little reason for Apple to offer a public API to do this, because any time you would be able to invoke it is when the keyboard is showing anyway, which would contain the button to activate it.

Comment: While you would only invoke it when the keyboard is showing, there's an obvious benefit for being able to just hit one button/field rather than a text field and then tapping on a tiny, itty-bitty microphone icon inside the keyboard each time. However, it does indeed seem to not be a priority for mobile OS devs.